# React SSR: excluding a component from the hydration process

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a react app that's using SSR, but when the page loads, and before hydration begins, I'm injecting some html (like ads) to some placeholders I've created inside the app. This, obviously, throws errors during hydration.

I tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `<div class="container" style="text-align: center"></div>`}} />
```

but I'm still getting an error: "prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match."

Is there a better solution for this issue?